# Issue with serialised data (jQuery sortable > PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using `.sortable('serialize')` in jQuery UI to pass updated positions of sortable items to a database. What I'm struggling to understand is how I manipulate that serialised data in order to update the positions in the database. Using `foreach` doesn't appear to be working.

```
jQuery:
-------
$('#sort').sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
                var data = sortBlock.sortable('serialize');
                updatePos(data);
            }
});

function updatePos(data) {
    ...     
    request = $.ajax({
        url:        url,
        method:     'post',
        data:       data
    });
    ...
}

PHP:
----
$entry = $_POST['data'];

$dbc = mysqli_connect(<connects>);

$i = 0;
foreach ($entry as $value) {
    $insert = 'UPDATE <table> SET <column> = '.$i;
    $i++;
}

Serialised data:
---------------
product[]=0&product[]=1...
```

Comment: Where do you assign `$entry`?

Comment: @BA_Webimax Added above: `$entry = $_POST['data'];`

Comment: Try `$entry = $_POST['product'];`

Comment: @BA_Webimax If I do that, I get an 'undefined index' error.

Comment: What does `var_dump( $_POST );` produce for output?

Comment: @BA_Webimax It produces: `array(1){["data"]=>string(107)"product[]=0&product[]=2&product[]=1&product[]=3&product[]=4&product[]=5&product[]=6&product[]=7&product[]=8"}`

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code are you setting `$entry` as `$_POST`? A good debugging function in PHP for this is `print_r`. `foreach` should be working as expected:

```
foreach($_POST['product'] as $value){
    $insert = 'UPDATE <table> SET <column> = '.$i;
    $i++;
}
```

A good debugging function in PHP for this is `print_r`. Try adding `print_r($_POST)` to your PHP code to see the format of the `POST`ed data that PHP received.

You can use PHP's `parse_str` method to parse this string into its constituent variables. E.g., `parse_str($_POST,$output);` will create the array in `$output['product']`. Or you can try using .sortable('toArray'); instead to format the data properly on the frontend

Comment: Yes, setting `$entry` as `$_POST`. If I use `print_r` I get output as per the 'Serialised data' section of my code block above. If I run the `foreach` I get the following error: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.